# Listar una serie de registros y filtrarlos por fecha a traves de un input date

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, datepicker

Estoy desarrollando una pequeña aplicación que me permita listar una serie de registros de una base de datos, filtrados por medio de la fecha de registro, que será seleccionada por medio de un `input` de tipo `date`.

**vistas/hombrehora.php**

```
<section class="content">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="box">
                    <div class="box-header with-border">
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        <h1 class="box-title">Control de Hombre Hora </h1>
                          <button class="btn btn-success" id="btnagregar" onclick="mostrarform(true)"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>  Agregar</button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="datePicker" id="datePicker" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-3 box-tools">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnactualizar" onclick="actualizar_lista($('#datePicker').val());return false;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- /.box-header -->
                    <!-- centro -->
                    <div class="panel-body table-responsive" id="listadoregistros">
                        <table id="tbllistado" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
                          <thead>
                            <th>Opciones</th>
                            <th>Grado</th>
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
                            <th>Apellido Materno</th>
                            <th>Periodo 1</th>
                            <th>Periodo 2</th>
                            <th>Periodo 3</th>
                            <th>Periodo 4</th>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>                            
                          </tbody>
                          <tfoot>
                            <th>Opciones</th>
                            <th>Grado</th>
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
                            <th>Apellido Materno</th>
                            <th>Periodo 1</th>
                            <th>Periodo 2</th>
                            <th>Periodo 3</th>
                            <th>Periodo 4</th>
                          </tfoot>
                        </table> 
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.box-header -->
                    <!-- centro -->
                    <div class="panel-body" id="formularioregistros">
                        <form name="formulario" id="formulario" method="POST">
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>FECHA</label>
                            <input type="hidden" name="id_hh" id="id_hh">
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="fecha" id="fecha" required>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>RUT:</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="rut_usuario" id="rut_usuario" maxlength="8" placeholder="RUT" required>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>HORA(*):</label>
                            <select id="hora_1" name="hora_1" class="form-control selectpicker" required>
                              <option value="08:00:00" selected>Periodo 1 (08:00 - 09:59)</option>
                            </select> 
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>MOTIVO:</label>
                            <select id="motivo_1" name="motivo_1" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" required>
                              <option value="1">FLA</option>
                              <option value="2">228</option>
                              <option value="3">COM</option>
                              <option value="4">LIC</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>HORA(*):</label>
                            <select id="hora_2" name="hora_2" class="form-control selectpicker" required>
                              <option value="10:00:00">Periodo 2 (10:00 - 11:59)</option>
                            </select> 
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>MOTIVO:</label>
                           <select id="motivo_2" name="motivo_2" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" required>
                            <option value="1">FLA</option>
                            <option value="2">228</option>
                            <option value="3">COM</option>
                            <option value="4">LIC</option>
                           </select>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>HORA(*):</label>
                            <select id="hora_3" name="hora_3" class="form-control selectpicker" required>
                              <option value="12:00:00">Periodo 3 (12:00 - 13:59)</option>
                            </select> 
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>MOTIVO:</label>
                            <select id="motivo_3" name="motivo_3" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" required>
                              <option value="1">FLA</option>
                              <option value="2">228</option>
                              <option value="3">COM</option>
                              <option value="4">LIC</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>HORA(*):</label>
                            <select id="hora_4" name="hora_4" class="form-control selectpicker" required>
                              <option value="14:00:00">Periodo 4 (14:00 - 17:00)</option>
                            </select> 
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>MOTIVO:</label>
                            <select id="motivo_4" name="motivo_4" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" required>
                              <option value="1">FLA</option>
                              <option value="2">228</option>
                              <option value="3">COM</option>
                              <option value="4">LIC</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnGuardar"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Guardar</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="cancelarform()" type="button"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i> Cancelar</button>
                          </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <!--Fin centro -->
                  </div><!-- /.box -->
              </div><!-- /.col -->
          </div><!-- /.row -->
      </section><!-- /.content -->
```

Implementé un `switch` con un `case` **listar()** en el archivo **hombrehora.php**, para llamarlo desde el `js` **hombrehora.js** por medio de `ajax` y listarlo por medio de `datatables`.

**ajax/hombrehora.php**

```
$hh=new Hombrehora();
$id_hh=isset($_POST["id_hh"])?limpiarCadena($_POST["id_hh"]):"";
$fecha=isset($_POST["fecha"])?limpiarCadena($_POST["fecha"]):"";
$fecha_sql=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fecha));//formatear la fecha para Mysql
$rut_usuario=isset($_POST["rut_usuario"])?limpiarCadena($_POST["rut_usuario"]):"";
$hora_1=isset($_POST["hora_1"])?limpiarCadena($_POST["hora_1"]):"";
$hora_2=isset($_POST["hora_2"])?limpiarCadena($_POST["hora_2"]):"";
$hora_3=isset($_POST["hora_3"])?limpiarCadena($_POST["hora_3"]):"";
$hora_4=isset($_POST["hora_4"])?limpiarCadena($_POST["hora_4"]):"";
$motivo_1=isset($_POST["motivo_1"])?limpiarCadena($_POST["motivo_1"]):"";
$motivo_2=isset($_POST["motivo_2"])?limpiarCadena($_POST["motivo_2"]):"";
$motivo_3=isset($_POST["motivo_3"])?limpiarCadena($_POST["motivo_3"]):"";
$motivo_4=isset($_POST["motivo_4"])?limpiarCadena($_POST["motivo_4"]):"";
$datePicker=isset($_POST["fechaSelect"])?limpiarCadena($_POST["fechaSelect"]):"";
echo $datePicker;


switch ($_GET["op"]){
    case 'listar':

            $rspta=$hh->listar($datePicker);
            $data= Array();
            while ($reg=$rspta->fetch_object()){

                $data[]=array(
                    "0"=>'<button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="mostrar('.$reg->id.')"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>',
                    "1"=>$reg->grado,
                    "2"=>$reg->nombre_usuario,
                    "3"=>$reg->apellido_pat,
                    "4"=>$reg->apellido_mat,
                    "5"=>$reg->mot_1,
                    "6"=>$reg->mot_2,
                    "7"=>$reg->mot_3,
                    "8"=>$reg->mot_4,
                    "9"=>$reg->rut,
                    "10"=>$reg->fecha
                    );
            }
            $results = array(
                "sEcho"=>1, //Información para el datatables
                "iTotalRecords"=>count($data), //enviamos el total registros al datatable
                "iTotalDisplayRecords"=>count($data), //enviamos el total registros a visualizar
                "aaData"=>$data);
            echo json_encode($results);

        break;
    }
```

Función listar.

**modelos/Hombrehora.php**

```
Class Hombrehora
{
    //Implementamos nuestro constructor
    public function __construct()
    {

    }
public function listar($datePicker)
    {
        $sql="SELECT a.id,
                     a.rut,
                     b.rut as rut_usuario,
                     b.nombre as nombre_usuario,
                     b.apellido_1 as apellido_pat,
                     b.apellido_2 as apellido_mat,
                     b.grado as grado,
                     a.fecha,
                     a.motivo_1,
                     a.motivo_2,
                     a.motivo_3,
                     a.motivo_4,
                     c.id_motivos,
                     c.nom_motivo as mot_1,
                     d.id_motivos,
                     d.nom_motivo as mot_2,
                     e.id_motivos,
                     e.nom_motivo as mot_3,
                     f.id_motivos,
                     f.nom_motivo as mot_4
                FROM hombre_hora_reg a
                     INNER JOIN usuario b ON a.rut=b.rut 
                     INNER JOIN motivos c ON a.motivo_1=c.id_motivos
                     INNER JOIN motivos d ON a.motivo_2=d.id_motivos
                     INNER JOIN motivos e ON a.motivo_3=e.id_motivos
                     INNER JOIN motivos f ON a.motivo_4=f.id_motivos
                     WHERE a.fecha='$datePicker'"; 
        return ejecutarConsulta($sql);
    }

}
```

Que recibe el parámetro **$datePicker** y hace un `select` a la base de datos en cuestión, filtrando por el **$datePicker**.

Para poder capturar el valor del **$datePicker** del `HTML` creé una función en un archivo `js`.

**scripts/hombrehora.js**

```
var tabla;


//Función que se ejecuta al inicio
function init(){
    mostrarform(false);


    setInputDate("#datePicker");
    setInputDate("#fecha");

    listar();

    $("#formulario").on("submit",function(e)
    {
        guardaryeditar(e);  
    })

}

//fecha actual del cliente en base a su zona horaria
function setInputDate(_id){
    var _dat = document.querySelector(_id);
    var hoy = new Date(),
        d = hoy.getDate(),
        m = hoy.getMonth()+1, 
        y = hoy.getFullYear(),
        data;

    if(d < 10){
        d = "0"+d;
    };
    if(m < 10){
        m = "0"+m;
    };

    data = y+"-"+m+"-"+d;
    console.log(data);
    _dat.value = data;
}

    function actualizar_lista(fechaSelect){

            var parametros = {
                    "fechaSelect" : fechaSelect
                };
            $.ajax({
                    data: parametros,
                    url: '../ajax/hombrehora.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    success:  function (response) {
                    bootbox.alert(response);

                }
         });

    }


    function listar()
    {
        tabla=$('#tbllistado').dataTable(
        {
            "aProcessing": true,//Activamos el procesamiento del datatables
            "aServerSide": true,//Paginación y filtrado realizados por el servidor
            dom: 'Bfrtip',//Definimos los elementos del control de tabla
            buttons: [                
                        'copyHtml5',
                        'excelHtml5',
                        'csvHtml5',
                        'pdf'
                    ],
            "ajax":
                    {
                        url: '../ajax/hombrehora.php?op=listar',
                        type : "get",
                        dataType : "json",                      
                        error: function(e){
                            console.log(e.responseText);    
                        }
                    },
            "bDestroy": true,
            "iDisplayLength":15,//Paginación
            "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]]//Ordenar (columna,orden)
        }).DataTable();


    }
```

El problema que tengo es que cuando quiero que mi función **listar()** me liste los registros, basado en el parámetro **$datePicker** que está recibiendo, no me lista ningún registro, porque recibe el valor del **$datePicker** vació, siendo que la petición de `ajax` es respondida con el valor de la fecha seleccionada en el `input type:date` **#datePicker** del `HTML` *(me muestra el valor de la fecha selecionada en el bootbox que programé)*, pero la función **listar()** no recibe ese valor y por ende, me muestra el `datatable` vació.

Ahora, si coloco el valor de **$datePicker** de manera directa como un valor de fecha, como por ejemplo:

```
$datePicker='2019-12-18';
```

Me lista los registros que tengo almacenados bajo ese parámetro sin problemas.

Es mas que obvio que un sistema así requiere de un selector de fechas dinámico para generar las consultas y mostrar la información y es por eso que no me sirve dejarlo estático.

Alguien me podría orientar porqué me puede estar pasando esto?. O si tiene una mejor manera de capturar un `input` de tipo `date` y pasarlo como parámetro a una consulta y así obtener el resultado requerido.

De antemano, muchas gracias por su ayuda y me disculpo además, si no he sido capaz de explicarme o hacerme entender como corresponde. Con vuestra ayuda y consejos iré ganando experiencia para poder orientar mejor mis dudas.

Saludos.

Comment: Si cargas la pagina, normalmente y seleccionas una fecha desde el datepicker, y en la consola pon esto `$('#datePicker').val()` que te retorna?

Comment: Revisa que tu `input` de tipo `date` esté enviando la fecha en el mismo formato que lo pones de manera estática, es decir, **2019-12-18**. Por lo que alcanzo a ver, lo envía de esta forma **12/18/2019**... Esa sería la razón de que no te devuelva resultados. si ese es el caso, debes cambiar el formato del `input`.

Comment: @jolsalazar al elegir una fecha del datepicker y luego ejecutar la consola con  $('#datePicker').val(), obtengo valores de fecha en el formato 'YYYY-mm-dd'
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Wb1pwnJWXBX2mGoJyf9vBNiwlCcYCong

Answer (score 1):

Primero, asegúrate de tener un valor adecuado en la variable, convirtiéndolo a "tiempo" (segundos transcurridos desde 1-ene/1970 0:00:00)

```
<?php
$datePicker = isset($_POST['fechaSelect'])
    ? strtotime(limpiarCadena($_POST['fechaSelect'])) // Convertir a tiempo
    : time(); // Hora actual

// Finalmente, formatea para incluir en consulta:
$datePicker = date('Y-m-d', $datePicker);
```

[strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php) puede convertir desde diferentes [formatos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.formats.date.php), por lo que no deberías tener mayor problema si tu script está devolviendo una fecha válida.

Comment: hice tal como me señalaste en tu respuesta y la selección en el selectpicker empezo a devolver los registros correspondientes a la fecha seleccionada, lo que significa que esta enviando la fecha en el formato correcto. Te agradezco mucho aquello. Ahora quería provechar de pedir tu ayuda para entender como poder visualizar esa consulta a la base de datos en mi datatable, ya que la estoy obteniendo en el bootbox de mi funcion actualizar_lista() y lo que necesito es que al cambiar mi selectPicker y darle al boton "btnactualizar" , se vuelva a ejecutar la funcion listar y rellenar el datatables

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=13-AUjfG46YDF21BUhMOTCwfp7VJGs_ce
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TTAQVHOmjU2u28OyOR6VP_FW8nkrWWgi

Comment: se olvido agregar que a la función actualizar_lista() del archivo js le realice una modificación, que causo la respuesta en el bootbox.

`function actualizar_lista(fechaSelect)
{
 
 var parametros = {
                "fechaSelect" : fechaSelect
            };
     $.ajax({
        data: parametros,
         url: '../ajax/hombrehora.php?op=listar',
         type: 'POST',
         success:  function (response) {
          bootbox.alert(response);
          
         }
     });`

Comment: Si tienes otras dudas lo mejor es crear una nueva pregunta.